# Queue several QTimers calls to slots

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, qtimer, qeventloop

I'm using a library where I need to call a trigger function that starts some processing (starts a thread that does the job) and returns immediatly. Then when the processing is finished a signal is emitted.

This needs to be done periodically based on different parameters. Since other calls to the trigger function must not be done while processing I would need to queue them in some way. I thought about using a QEventLoop ("loop") but without luck so far.

Please look at this piece of code:

```
test::test()
    {
    connect(&timer,   SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timerSlot()));
    connect(&timer2,  SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timer2Slot()));
    connect(&library, SIGNAL(processingFinished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

    timer.setInterval(2000);
    timer.start();

    timer2.setInterval(4000);
    timer2.start();
    }

void test::timerSlot()
    {
    loop.exec();
    startProcessing(some_parameters);
    }

void test::timer2Slot()
    {
    loop.exec();
    startProcessing(some_other_parameters);
    }
```

The issue is that when loop.exec() is called while processing I get the message:

```
QEventLoop::exec: instance xxxxxx has already called exec()
```

What would be the right way to do what I intend?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to prevent the timer slots from executing while you are processing parameters, you can have the timer slots disconnect the signal-slot connection and reconnect it when processing is finished.  This will not "queue" additional timer events that occur during processing, though. Can you explain what you're trying to achieve by queuing the timer events? Do you want all the timer events that were queued up to execute at once when processing is complete?

Comment: Hello @deGoot and thank you for your answer! It's a server-client model. I need to poll periodically the client to update information on the server. There are different types of polls that should occur every x seconds. I'm not interested in queuing all the pending polls but at least if two occur at the same time or while a previous poll is taking place I want to execute the last after the first finishes. About your suggestion I believe it may produce significant distortions to the polling periods since timers will call slot every x seconds plus all the "pauses" in the middle.

Comment: In that case, you can just use a member `bool m_is Processing` variable and wrap the timer code in `if(!m_isProcessing)`. And you can also have a member variable to indicate if another timer went off while you were processing. And reset m_isProcessing and launch the other timer's action once processing is complete.

Comment: Thank you @deGoot! Yours is a very simple solution, so simple that was out of my mind and which I couldn't figure out before thinking about complex alternatives. It solved my problem. If you want to post an answer I will happily set it as accepted.

Comment: I'm glad my suggestion works for you. I know what it's like to miss a simple solution when you think you're dealing with a complex problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is to introduce a member variable, for example, `bool m_isProcessing`, start processing only if `m_isProcess == false`, then set it to `true` when you start processing and reset it to `false` when processing is complete. Since the slots for your `test QObject` execute on the GUI/main thread, you don't need to worry about synchronization between timer slots and the slot that will execute when processing is finished.

If you want to keep track of events that occur during processing, you can use the same method: introduce a member variable to the `test` class to track the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for [Qt::QueuedConnection](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum).

> Qt::QueuedConnection  2   The slot is invoked when control returns to the event loop of the receiver's thread. The slot is executed in the receiver's thread.

Therefore, you could write something like this:

```
connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(timerSlot()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
connect(&timer2, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(timer2Slot()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

For details, you could look into the well-known mandelbrot example how this is done in there, although it is using worker threads:

[Mandelbrot Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtcore-mandelbrot-example.html)

Comment: Hello @LaszloPapp thank you for your answer. It seems that despite I make the connection queued with Qt::QueuedConnection loop.exec() is called more than once before loop:quit().

Comment: @Fracu: remove your loop completely.

Comment: The slots called by the timers are just triggering the library processing. They finish immediately. So the queue needs to go further than that. The next slot call should only be permitted after the previous processing has finished (which occurs when the library emits a signal which was quitting the loop in my example). Its an asynchronous processing. I believe that internally the library is starting threads.

Comment: AI would just remove the loops... Use the application event loop, only.

Comment: No, it didn't work since slot is calling "startProcessing()", and this function is just starting a thread that does the job, after the thread is started it returns immediatly to main event loop and subsequent calls to the slots are performed (we don't want that). Only when the thread has finish its job (seconds after) it emits a signal that it's connected (at last) in my example to loop::quit().